# JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge for Cassandra on Ubuntu

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, unixodbc, jdbc-odbc

I want to create JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge on Ubuntu, and then want to access in Java. 
I installed unixODBC and Cassandra ODBC driver and set DSN in `odbc.ini` file and Driver in `odbcinst.ini` file and as well as also export both file and and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also. But it gives me error, could not find `ODBCINSTGetProperties()`.

When I run program on Eclipse, then it giving me below error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so: undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv
```

for this export `LD_DEBUG=ALL`. But i did not understand from this .

Answer (score 0):

Note that the JVM-bundled JDBC-ODBC Bridge was never intended for production use, and has been dropped from Java 8, to which all Java users should upgrade for various security reasons.  This JVM-bundled Bridge appears to be the source of your reported error.

My employer makes an enterprise-grade [JDBC Driver for ODBC Data Sources](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/), which we expect to work fine against the Cassandra ODBC driver, whether you stay with unixODBC or shift to the [the iODBC driver manager](http://www.iodbc.org/) (open source like unixODBC; maintained by my employer).